# Select day of month as start of date range using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset indexed on a timeseries. I want to get all data for the dates from the 18th to 13 days later from the rows in the data. E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    (datetime(2013, 2, 16),2), 
    (datetime(2013, 2, 18),5),  # 
    (datetime(2013, 2, 19),6),  # 
    (datetime(2013, 3, 1), 7),  # 
    (datetime(2013, 3, 17),1), 
    (datetime(2013, 3, 20),3),  #
    (datetime(2013, 3, 25),4),  #
    (datetime(2013, 4, 1), 8)],
    columns=["time_slot", "data"], 
    index=["time_slot"])
```

Only the rows marked with `#` should be included.

Doing:

```
days = df.ix[df.index.day == 18].index
for d in days:
    print df.ix[d:d+timedelta(days=13)]
```

Will only print the first three marked records. Is there a way to select a date range based on the day of month without explicitly specifying a month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd do this but I wanted to play around with dates in Pandas more so gave it a go.  I'm pretty new to Pandas - I've found it easiest to work with a date index by creating an additional column.  No doubt someone can do it more concisely.

I think the following does what you wanted:

```
from datetime import *
import pandas as pd

from_day = 15
plus_days = 18

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
(datetime(2013, 2, 16),2), 
(datetime(2013, 2, 18),5),  # 
(datetime(2013, 2, 19),6),  # 
(datetime(2013, 3, 1), 7),  # 
(datetime(2013, 3, 17),1), 
(datetime(2013, 3, 20),3),  #
(datetime(2013, 3, 25),4),  #
(datetime(2013, 4, 1), 8)],
columns=["time_slot", "data"], 
index=["time_slot"])

df.insert(0,'days',df.index)
df.days = df.days.apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

Then you can query the dataframe with your inequality:

```
df[(df['days']>=from_day) & (df['days'] < from_day + plus_days)].data
```

Clearly with from_day set to *15* and plus_days *18* will always result in all days from day 15 but I think this will work in general.

### Update

Using my from_day and plus days (but plus_days set to 13 as you asked for), the following includes the 1st to 3rd of Feb. 2013 as I think you want.:

```
df.insert(0,'adjusted_day',df.index)
df.adjusted_day = df.adjusted_day.apply(lambda x: (x + timedelta(days=-plus_days)).day) 
df[(df.index.day>=from_day) | ((df.adjusted_day <=from_day) & (df.adjusted_day >=from_day-plus_days))]
```

Comment: As with K.Chen's answer this does not catch the case of February.

Comment: Your solution works and is probably better than mine. I ended up making a selection with something like `df.ix[(df.index.day >= 18) | ( (df.index.month == 3) & (df.index.day <= 2) ) | ((df.index.month % 2 == 1) & (df.index.day == 1))]`. I named the different indexers as to make them clearer. Not sure which way is more performant on large datasets though.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
df[df.index.day>=18]
```

Comment: It does not catch the corner case for feburary. 18th feb + 13 days => 2nd or 3rd february, depending on leap year.